# Import values ​from a list into a dataframe quickly using R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I would like to understand how to create a data frame faster by extracting data from a list. In
particular I have a list of 40 elements that have a different length. I am using this method but it is really slow.

```
data1 <- output_list[1] %>% data.frame()
data2 <- output_list[2] %>% data.frame()
data3 <- output_list[3] %>% data.frame()
data4 <- output_list[4] %>% data.frame()
data5 <- output_list[5] %>% data.frame()
data6 <- output_list[6] %>% data.frame()
data7 <- output_list[7] %>% data.frame()
........
........
data39 <- output_list[39] %>% data.frame()
data40<- output_list[40] %>% data.frame()


general.data <- rbind(data1, data2, data3, ......, data39, data40)
```

How can I speed up all this in a few lines?
Thanks everyone in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all elements of the list are data.frames and have the same structure, then the easiest and fastest way will be:

```
library(data.table)

general.data <- rbindlist(output_list)
```

Comment: `dplyr::bind_rows()` does the same thing. It also has a `.id` argument if you want to keep either the name of the list element or its order (if the list element isn't named).